Using StreamingDataSound from Kira in GUI
I am unable to load StreamingSoundData and play it through UI (iced).
struct Noise {
    sound: Option<StaticSoundData>,
    manager: AudioManager,
   
}
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum Message {
    File,
    Play(Option<StaticSoundData>),
}

  async fn get_file_test() -> Option<StaticSoundData> {
    let settings = StaticSoundSettings::new().loop_region(0.0..);
    println!("reach..");
    let sound_data = StaticSoundData::from_file("bells.mp3", settings);
    match sound_data {
        Ok(s) => Some(s),
        Err(_) => None,
    }
}

Now when I try to do this with StreamingSoundData, it does not work:
First StreamingSoundData::from_file function returns Result<StreamingSoundData<FromFileError>, FromFileError>.
If I try to cast this to Option, then inside of Message enum I get issue that FromFileError does not implement Debug and Clone.
And I really dont want to load some of the files inside of a StaticSoundData since that is just saved in memory, I would like to have constant stream for bigger files.
    use iced::{
    advanced::Application,
    executor,
    program::{Appearance, DefaultStyle},
    widget::{button, container, Column, Row},
    window::Settings,
    Command, Renderer, Theme,
};

use kira::{
    manager::{backend::DefaultBackend, AudioManager, AudioManagerSettings},
    sound::static_sound::{StaticSoundData, StaticSoundSettings},
    sound::streaming::{StreamingSoundData, StreamingSoundSettings},
    sound::FromFileError,
};

pub fn main() -> iced::Result {
    Noise::run(iced::Settings {
        window: Settings {
            size: iced::Size {
                width: 300.0,
                height: 400.0,
            },
            ..Default::default()
        },
        ..Default::default()
    })
}

struct Noise {
    sound: Option<StaticSoundData>,
    manager: AudioManager,
    stream: StreamingSoundData<FromFileError>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum Message {
    File,
    Play(Option<StaticSoundData>),
    Stream,
    StreamStart(Option<StreamingSoundData<FromFileError>>),
}

impl Application for Noise {
    type Executor = executor::Default;
    type Message = Message;
    type Theme = Theme;
    type Flags = ();
    type Renderer = Renderer;

    fn new(_flags: Self::Flags) -> (Self, iced::Command<Self::Message>) {
        (
            Self {
                sound: None,
                manager: AudioManager::<DefaultBackend>::new(AudioManagerSettings::default())
                    .ok()
                    .unwrap(),
                stream: None,
            },
            Command::perform(get_file_test(), Message::Play),
        )
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("Loop")
    }

    fn update(&mut self, message: Self::Message) -> iced::Command<Self::Message> {
        match message {
            Message::File => Command::perform(get_file(), Message::Play),
            Message::Play(s) => {
                println!("file will play...");
                self.sound = s;
                self.manager.play(self.sound.clone().unwrap()).unwrap();
                Command::none()
            }
            Message::Stream => {
                self.manager.play(self.stream.clone().unwrap()).unwrap();

                Command::none()
            }
            Message::StreamStart(s) => {
                self.stream = s;
                Command::none()
            }
        }
    }

    fn view(&self) -> iced::Element<'_, Self::Message, Self::Theme, Self::Renderer> {
        let layout = Row::new();
        let con = Column::new()
            .push(button("Add").on_press(Message::Add))
            .push(button("Fetch").on_press(Message::File));
        container(layout.push(con)).into()
    }

    fn theme(&self) -> Self::Theme {
        Self::Theme::default()
    }

    fn style(&self, theme: &Self::Theme) -> Appearance {
        theme.default_style()
    }
}

async fn get_file() -> Option<StaticSoundData> {
    let settings = StaticSoundSettings::new().loop_region(0.0..);
    println!("getting the file..");
    let sound_data = StaticSoundData::from_file("rain.mp3", settings);
    match sound_data {
        Ok(s) => Some(s),
        Err(_) => None,
    }
}
async fn get_file_test() -> Option<StaticSoundData> {
    let settings = StaticSoundSettings::new().loop_region(0.0..);
    println!("reach..");
    let sound_data = StaticSoundData::from_file("rain.mp3", settings);
    match sound_data {
        Ok(s) => Some(s),
        Err(_) => None,
    }
}
fn get_stream() -> Option<StreamingSoundData<FromFileError>> {
    let settings = StreamingSoundSettings::new().loop_region(0.0..);
    println!("reach..");
    let sound_data = kira::sound::streaming::StreamingSoundData::from_file("bells.mp3", settings);
    match sound_data {
        Ok(s) => Some(s),
        Err(_) => None,
    }
}


Note: your match is just Result::ok

Can you add what you've tried as a [mre]?

@cafce25 here it is https://pastebin.com/XKNKaUFF note, if you comment out everything regarding Stream (messages and struct field) it will work (play the sound i want it to using staticsounddata.I dont know how to overcome this.
thanks

Please add that to the question itself, external only content is problematic for several reasons.

@cafce25 Done, i added directly to the question
